# Building Mesa from git - can not "apt-get build-dep mesa"

Tags: apt, mesa

I'm trying to follow this guide [mesa compiling and installing](https://www.mesa3d.org/install.html)

But when I get to this step

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mesa
```

I get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for mesa
```

I can't really seem to find anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I found the solution myself now

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Click the enable source code. And you should be able to run the command